# Google+ API get link to reshared activities

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Given a list of activity re-sharers how can I get the links to those individual shares:

[Reshare API call](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.listByActivity?activityId=z12asbxinx31z5bjt04cfdixgybzwheqq5g&collection=resharers&_h=2&)

There only seems to be a link to the users profile, not the actual [re-share](https://plus.google.com/103695813109371018473/posts/H69xZkXvQA1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plus.activities.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=116072750225437470888&collection=public&fields=items%28access%252CcrosspostSource%252Cprovider%252Ctitle%252Curl%29&_h=5&), search the post provider field for reshare, then determine from content whether it was your original post.